# Open modal popup on kendo-grid header double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

I want to open modal popup when kendo-grid header is double clicked.

I tried the following:

```
headerAttributes: { 'ondblclick':'openPopup()' }
```

This way, the popup opens correctly but it also sorts the grid (default functionality of grid).

Please suggest how to prevent grid to sort when header is double clicked.
I tried

```
ev.preventDefault();
return false;
```

but nothing works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:

```
$('#Grid').on("dblclick", "th.k-header",  function () {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: thnx for the rply, this will work, but it will also sorts the grid column. how can i prevent grid from sorting ?

Comment: You must mke click event to prevent default behaviour: `$('#Grid').on("click", "th.k-header",  function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});`